# NFS share write -only permission

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, nfs

Is that possible to implement NFS server in Ubuntu then set up "write-only" permission? I would  like to let all my clients can save their files to NFS share for backup but I don't want the client to read the file in the NFS share by `cat`  or `ls -al`

I am very new to Ubuntu, any help is appreciated!